# Protect yii2-apidoc generated html

Tags: yii2

I have generated api docs using the yii2-apidoc extension and have a nice working site with html-pages in a folder. 
However I do not want these pages to be publicly available, rather behind the normal login to my backend-site. Can't figure out a way to do it in Yii.

Tried to use renderFile() in a controller, but that still leaves wrong links to other asset-files (css).

Any ideas appreciated.